# How to pass these url encoded params in Phoenix plug test during post request so that Plug.Conn.read_body reads it?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

In a plug I have the following line of code in an Elixir/Phoenix plug module which works when a post request is sent to it.

```
{:ok, body, _} = Plug.Conn.read_body(conn)
# body is a url encoded param string
```

When I have the following test setup for the plug, body is an empty string when running the test. How do I pass in the parameters to the `post` call such that during test calling Plug.Conn.read_body(conn) will populate `body` with the url encoded param string?

```
  encoded_params =
    URI.encode_query(%{
      a: 2, b: 3
    })

  conn =
    conn
    |> put_req_header("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    |> post(
      Routes.custom_path(conn, :custom),
      encoded_params
    )
```

Comment: Do not encode params; `post/3` helper would do it for you.

Comment: I tried that at first, but then the `body` in {:ok, body, _} = Plug.Conn.read_body() was `--plug_conn_test--` in test mode which didn't match what happened in developer mode.

Comment: You may need to provide the post body in your tests, in the same way as you have provided the content-type header and the parameters.

Comment: Did you try to check what's inside `conn.body_params` ?

Comment: In dev mode, it's `%Plug.Conn.Unfetched{aspect: :body_params}` ; in test mode it's an Elixir map of the url encoded params passed into the post call.

Comment: @Everett - `You may need to provide the post body in your tests, in the same way as you have provided the content-type header and the parameters.` - isn't the post body going to be the encoded_params? Or is there another argument I'm missing?